# Select different languages using drop down and translate RoR 3.2 Ruby 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am having problems with select boxes and localization. I should connected with ajax/javascript somehow but not sure how. When user selects language a site should get translated to the chosen language. This is what I have so far.

application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  #some code which returns local language accoarding to IP
end
```

_header.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag set_locale_path do %>
  <%= select_tag :locale, options_for_select([['English', 'en'], ['Spanish', 'sp'], ['German', 'ge']]) %>
<% end %>
```

This header is in shared view folder and doesn't have related controller/model. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale]
end
```

search in guide [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: Thank you Adeptus but set_locale code is working properly. I am using some gem to help with it and it returns correct local language. So that is not the problem, the problem is when user selects different language in select box - nothing happens. And it should translate the page according to the chosen language.

Comment: so you can add "

  def default_url_options(options={})
    {:locale => I18n.locale}
  end  
  
" to application_controller. realy good [tutorial](http://blog.crowdint.com/2011/02/15/internationalizing-your-rails-app.html)

Comment: I did but still nothing changes when I click on select box value. Any other ideas?

Comment: you select box should reload page or be link_to("English", :locale => "en") to add locale in path